# How to guarantee clearing of nested std::array?

Tags: c++, stdarray

I have a nested `std::array` of `std::tuple`. For example,

```
std::array<std::array<std::pair<int*, float*>, 12>, 3> my_array;
```

How can I clear all elements so all the pointers are zeroed (i.e. `nullptr`)?

Comment: What about `std::array<std::array<std::pair<int*, float*>, 12>, 3> my_array{};`?

Comment: Just `my_array = {};`  ?

Comment: Do you also need returning dynamic memory or is this only for new arrays?

Comment: Remember to free those pointers first if they're pointing to dynamically allocated memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I clear all elements so all the pointers are zeroed (i.e. nullptrs)?

Since you're using `std::array`, you could just just assign an empty `std::array` to `my_array` as shown below:

```
my_array = {};
```